# Python: [object Object] showing up on page field

Tags: python, angularjs, google-app-engine

I am developing an angularjs app on google app engine however I have an issue displaying one of my `KeyProperty` fields `client`.

This is how the *KeyProperty* field is displaying (The other non KeyProperty elements are showing up fine);

**NB:** Post is *200 OK*

[image]

**model.py**

```
class Project(ndb.Model):
    projectID = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    startAt = ndb.DateTimeProperty(indexed=True)
    endAt = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    client = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Client')

class Client(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

**home.html element**

```
       <div class="form-group">
            <label>Client : </label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="Project.Client" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
```

In **handler.py**

```
def post(self):
    r = json.loads(self.request.body)
    print str(r)

    cl = Client(name=r['Client']).put()
    client_key = cl

    g = Project(projectID=int(r['ProjectID']),
        client=client_key,
        description=r['Description'],
        title=r['Title'],
        startAt=datetime.strptime(r['StartAt'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'),
        endAt=datetime.strptime(r['EndAt'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))

    project_key = g.put()
```

**angular**

```
eventClick: function (project) { 
                $scope.showSelected = true;

                var fromDate = moment(project.start).format('DD/MM/YYYY LT');
                var endDate  = moment(project.end).format('DD/MM/YYYY LT');

                $scope.Project = { 
                    ProjectID : project.projectID, 
                    Client : project.client,
                    Title : project.title,
                    Description: project.description,
                    Employees: project.employees,
                    StartAt : fromDate,
                    EndAt : endDate,
                    IsFullDay : false   
                }
                $scope.ShowModal()
            },
```

I am still learning my way to handling *KeyProperties*. Thanks for the help

**UPDATE**

This is the error I am getting when I type 'qwert' in the Client field;

[image]

Comment: Try to `console.log` this object and see what properties it has. What you want is probably one of its properties.

Comment: `[Object object]` means you have a complex object in hands. Try to change your code to `ng-model="Project.Client.name"` instead.

Comment: @FabioMenegazzo  yes that helped (field displays properly) when I added I changed to `ng-model = ng-model="Project.Client.name" `. However, after I add `.name`, when I try a new _post_, it takes me to the /edit endpoint handler instead of /save  handler

Comment: @lucasnadalutti please refer to the above response. thanks

Comment: apologies, from the above response, there was a small issue somewhere else. The actual error I meant is `BadValueError: Expected string, got {u'name': u'chelsea'}` when I type 'chelsea' for example, into the Client field. This is when I'm posting a new entry.

Comment: So, it is returning a dictionary.  Use `your_dictionary_name.name` to pull the `name` from that dict.

Comment: @GAEfan you mean as in 'Project.Client.name'? It  worked as earlier mentioned but now I get the BadValueError in python when I attempt to post a new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am talking about in your Python code.  The error log should tell you what line of your code was expecting a string.  That is where you need the `.name`

Comment: I have provided the error in the screenshot above (update). Error is coming from `cl = Client(name=r['Client']).put()` .I've tried `cl = Client(name=r['Client.name']).put()` but that gives me a key error.

Comment: I actually tweaked around and `cl = Client(name=r['Client']['name']).put()` works! Thanks